How to automate midjouney's discord interaction?
I need to automate one process of calling midjourney from discord in a spring boot session. I tried it using a bot and integrating that bot in my codebase, making that bot and midjourney's bot in the same server. But everytime I use slash command, like /imagine it doesn't pick midjourney. Its just a simple slash text. Later on i found that slash commands doesn't work with bot interaction with another bot.
Any way i can build this thing ? Or automate it ?
